# How to set up partial toprule and make even sub columns

Tags: tables

First thing first, my LaTeX code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%%% change contents font %%%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\large                              
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,font=large}
\centering \caption{REVENUE INTERESTS}
\begin{tabular}{
  *{5}{S[table-format=1.4]}
 }
  \toprule
& {Expense}  & {Oil/}       & {Plant}    &       \\
& {Interest} & {Condensate} & {Products} & {Gas} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\bf{INITIAL} & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\bf{FINAL}   & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\bf{REMARKS} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bf{ALL AMOUNTS ARE EXPRESSED IN THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS.}}\\
  \multicolumn{5}{l}{%
  \scriptsize
  %
}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

and export table looks like below,
[image: What I am currently at]

What I want to edit the table into,

**1. Partial Toprule line, make caption centered with shorten toprule. 
 2. Even sub column distribution
 3. Reduce the veritcal distance between caption and table itself.**

which should be looks like pic below,
[image: Hoping to finish like this]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a local command that sets all headers in a `\makebox` with the same width; experiment with the width until you're satisfied.

In the code I left just the packages necessary for typesetting the table. Note that you don't want `\caption`, as “Revenue Interests” is the header of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%% change contents font %%%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
%%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%%%

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\makebox[.15\textwidth]{#1}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.4]}
 }
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{REVENUE INTERESTS}}\\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
& {\fl{Expense}}  & {\fl{Oil/}}       & {\fl{Plant}}    &       \\
& {\fl{Interest}} & {\fl{Condensate}} & {\fl{Products}} & {\fl{Gas}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\textbf{INITIAL} & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\textbf{FINAL}   & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\textbf{REMARKS} & 
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ALL AMOUNTS ARE EXPRESSED IN THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS.}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You get right alignment with respect to the `\cmidrule` with the option `table-alignment=right`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%% change contents font %%%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
%%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%%%

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\newcommand{\fl}[1]{\makebox[.12\textwidth]{#1}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.4,table-alignment=right]}
 }
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{REVENUE INTERESTS}}\\
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
& {\fl{Expense}}  & {\fl{Oil/}}       & {\fl{Plant}}    &       \\
& {\fl{Interest}} & {\fl{Condensate}} & {\fl{Products}} & {\fl{Gas}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\textbf{INITIAL} & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\textbf{FINAL}   & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1.2345 \\
\textbf{REMARKS} & 
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ALL AMOUNTS ARE EXPRESSED IN THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS.}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I set all value and value only flush right?

Comment: @ChengZhang Flush right with respect to what? Believe me, you want them centered, because the headers have different widths.

Comment: @ egreg With respect to the right end of midrule. It's a typesetting requirement, otherwise I would definitely follow your advice.

Comment: @ChengZhang You have all my sympathy. `;-)`. Added.

Comment: How do I make another newcommand to control specific sub column width?

Comment: I mean column one I want 0.08\textwidth and other rest columns are 0.12\textwidth. I am not quite familiar with /newcommand and /makebox. Could only trail by error.

Comment: @ChengZhang Just use `\makebox[0.08\textwidth][l]{INITIAL}` in the first row. The width of an `l` column is determined by the widest item in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{multirow,array,varwidth,spreadtab,}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%%% change contents font %%%
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% just for showing only table
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
%%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%% %%%%
    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\large
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l}
\\
\\
\\[0.8em] % determined experimentally 
INITIAL         \\
FINAL           \\
REMARKS         \\%
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{S[table-format=1.4]}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{REVENUE INTERESTS.}} \\
    \toprule
{Expense}   &   {Oil/}      & {Plant}    &       \\
{Interest}  & {Condensate}  & {Products} & {Gas} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
1.2345      & 1.2345        & 1.2345    & 1.2345 \\
1.2345      & 1.2345        & 1.2345    & 1.2345 \\
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ALL AMOUNTS ARE EXPRESSED IN THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS.}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

In preamble I erase duplicate package. Since Caption is not enumerated, I put it in first row of second tabular environment.

[image]

**Edit:**
equal width of columns you can obtain to merge first and second row in second tabular environment (last one is wider since text in last row is to wide).

```
    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\large
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l}
\\
\\[0.75em] 
INITIAL         \\
FINAL           \\
\midrule
REMARKS         \\%
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{S[table-format=1.4]}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{REVENUE INTERESTS.}} \\
    \toprule
{Expense Interest}   
            &   {Oil/Condensate}      
                            & {Plant Products}    & {Gas} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4}
1.2345      & 1.2345        & 1.2345    & 1.2345 \\
1.2345      & 1.2345        & 1.2345    & 1.2345 \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{ALL AMOUNTS ARE EXPRESSED IN THOUSANDS OF DOLLARS.}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

I add just a content of table ...

[image]

Comment: Your answer perfectly fit my first and third questions, and I would applied your answer for sure. But do you have any idea how to get my second question and how to evenly distribute sub 4 columns ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your second question. Do you like to have al columns with equal with or something else?

Comment: With same width in each column. BTW, How to draw a midrule above [REMAKRS] row, since this is a combination of two tabular environment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See a code (it should be self explanatory. In each tabular i put '\midrule' and also put ``%`` after first tabular that i stick with next one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, well learned! Appreciated your kind help. Perfect answer!

Comment: Quick question, when I change [Expense Interest] into two rows, the uneven column just back. This table is the first one small table with other two small tables side by side. Later I would minimize the font and put 3 tables side by side in a row, so space means a lot to me. I need to use two row to define the sub-caption like[Expense Interest] and etc.